# I am trying to create_list in factory_bot rails limiting the sequence from an array of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

From straight ruby code i am trying to achieve a sequence in my factory spec to do something similar to this ruby block of code

```
domains = %w(gmail.com yahoo.com msn.com)
d = []
100.times do |n|
  d << domains[n % domains.length] 
end

puts d // this will print restricted strings from the array 100 times
```

which is what i am trying to achieve with sequence in rspec to test my code works after 100 records are created in the database which already has a validate inclusion in the model

heres my factory

```
trait :random do
  sequence(:local_government_area) do |l|
    lga = %w(zuru fakai sakaba)
      lga_to_save = []

      100.times do |n|
        lga_to_save << lga[n % lga.length]
      end

      puts lga_to_save
      puts l
        
      local_government_area { lga_to_save }
    end
  end
end
```

and its been called here

```
let(:hundred_students) { create_list(:biodata, 100, :random) }
```

i know my code is not close cause ive been debugging but i need to know how i can restrict a `create_list` to an `array` of `strings` for a `trait`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sequence code should not worry about the number of records, as `create_list` already do that. Try this:

```
trait :random do
    sequence(:local_government_area) do |n| 
       lga = %w(zuru fakai sakaba)
       lga[n % lga.length]
    end
end
```

And then:

```
let(:hundred_students) { create_list(:biodata, 100, :random) }
```